# I'm trying to create and fetch quizzes for a particular user using userId as parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm trying to create and fetch quizzes in router using NodeJs, but it keeps fetching me quizzes of every user and not only the user that is logged in

```
const prefix = "/:userId/quizzes";

router.get(`${prefix}/my-quizzes`, userAuth, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const quizes = await Quiz.find().populate({
      path: "category",
      select: ["name"],
    });

    res.send(quizes);
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(404).json({
      message: "Can't fetch quizes !",
      success: false,
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add a query using the proper `userId` taken from the `req.param`, like so:

```
await Quiz.find({userId: req.param.userId})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to filter your collection inside the `find`

Something like

```
Quiz.find({"userId": userId})
```

Comment: Now it keeps catching 404 error message.

Comment: Remove momentarily your try/catch to see your error message